# When will the 'prerender' or 'entitycreated' events be triggered

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I bind my callback function with those two event in the world plugin, but they never are triggered. I would like to know why. I can't find much information on the wiki.

Thanks.

The two functions I used are:

```
static ConnectionPtr    ConnectCreateEntity (T _subscriber)
```

and

```
static ConnectionPtr    ConnectPreRender (T _subscriber)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/5980/when-will-the-%27prerender%27-or-%27entitycreated%27-events-be-triggered/) by [EdwardC](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/484/edwardc/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-04-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) on 2014-04-24**:
I think PreRender will only be triggered in System-Plugins (client side)

**Comment by [EdwardC](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/484/edwardc/) on 2014-06-06**:
Yap, you're right. I figured it out somehow. But still, thanks~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Answered in comments.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2014-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0